# Update data into mysql database by clicking on a link

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I there a way to update data into mysql database when click on a link? I want create a comment voting system on my site so when user clicks on a "Vote for this comment" link, +1 should be sent into database...

How is that possible?

Comment: Hi, read the discussion bellow my (dwich) answer. You should think about redesigning your poll and use form with method POST instead of links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="/vote.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="item" value="999">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Vote Up">
</form>
```

**PHP** - *vote.php*

```
<?php
if( !isset( $_POST['item'] ) ) {
  header( 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found' );
  die( '<html><body>Missing <i>item</i> parameter</body></html>' );
}
$item = (int) $_POST['item'];
if( @mysql_query( "UPDATE `items` SET `vote`=`vote`+1 WHERE `id`=$item" ) ) {
  if( isset( $_POST['format'] ) && $_POST['format']=='json' )
    die( json_encode( array( 'result'=>true ) ) );
  die( '<html><body>Score for item #'.$item.' incremented</body></html>' );
}
header( 'HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error' );
if( isset( $_POST['format'] ) && $_POST['format']=='json' )
    die( json_encode( array( 'result'=>false ) ) );
die( '<html><body>Score for item #'.$item.' FAILED to incremented</body></html>' );
```

**jQuery**

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
  $( 'form[action="/vote.php"]' ).each( function() {
    $( this ).replaceWith( '<span class="vote" parameter="item='+$( this ).find( 'input[name="item"]' ).attr( 'value' )+'">Vote Up</span>' );
  } );
  $( 'span[class="vote"]' ).click( function() {
    var $this = $( this );
    $.ajax( {
      type     : 'POST' ,
      url      : '/vote.php' ,
      data     : $( this ).attr( 'parameter' )+'&format=json' ,
      dataType : 'json' ,
      success  : function( data , status , XHR ) {
        if( data.result===true )
          alert( 'Voted Up' );
        else
          alert( 'Something Unexpected Borked' );
      } ,
      error    : function( XHR , status , error ) {
        alert( 'Something Borked' );
      }
    } );
  } );
} );
```

**Note:** This is an untested solution, but would be what I would consider a starting point to commence debugging and testing.

**UPDATED:** Changed behaviour to POST based on advice from @Artefacto.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, create a PHP scripts that updates the database as if a regular form had been submitted and then use Javascript to make a request to that script when the link is clicked.

See [AJAX Introduction](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_intro.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) (with one of the available frameworks jQuery, mootools, Dojo,...): whenever a user clicks on a link, an attached action get's triggered and does the "magic".

Mostly this will be sending an AJAX request to the server with the comment id and/or any other data needed and the script will update the database.

SInce you already tagged the question with jQuery, http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML:

```
<a href="update.php?answer_id=1">vote</a>
```

In PHP:

```
$Q = 'UPDATE `votes` SET `count` = `count` + 1 WHERE `answer_id` = ?';
$db_connection->prepare($Q);
$db_connection->bind_param('i', $_GET['answer_id']);
$db_connection->execute();
```

When you have this ready, use AJAX to do it without reloading a page. Bind a function to voting links and send the request to a webpage in a same way but asynchronously.

In jQuery use something like:

```
$.get('update.php?id=1', function(data) {
  alert('Thanks for voting');
});
```

Comment: Same. Just add class="vote" to ahref and then use techique called http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript
Use jQuery to bind a function to all ahrefs with class=vote

Comment: @Artefacto: Why should you use POST? Just interested as I would think that it shouldn't really matter either way.

Comment: @Lucanos RFC 2616 9.1.1 " In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and
   HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action
   other than retrieval."

Comment: That's true but in this case it's irrelevant. He's asking how to update his database by clicking a link. If you click a link, you have to use a GET method. Author should redesign hes poll to allow voting using form and POST method.

Comment: @dwich No, you can generate a POST request by clicking on a link with Javascript.

Comment: @Artefacto: Learn something new every day. Mind you, I believe that this RFC would have to be one of the most often overlooked/ignored, especially with the number of APIs out there which only offer GET interactions, whether retrieving or adding data. If you are a proponent for standards, you might want to submit a postJSON() function for jQuery.

Comment: @Artefacto: (PS). What @dwich is saying is that a pure POST action cannot be submitted by clicking on a vanilla `<a href="">link</a>`, which is true. Whilst that functionality can be added, as you say, with javascript, it makes things difficult when trying to create graceful degradation.

Comment: @Lucanos with vanilla anchors, even worse -- not only are you using a method that's conceptually wrong, now the web crawlers will also vote.

Comment: @Artefacto: That's what I wrote: "Author should redesign his poll". Use form (POST) instead of links. We should comment author's question directly to notify him :)