# Update data in my database when we click on a link

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I want to update my data into my database when a user click on a link on my page. I did some search on stack overflow and found some related questions but I couldn't understand how they work, for example i found [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222697/update-data-into-mysql-database-by-clicking-on-a-link)

The code that I display the message is the below...

```
?>
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(status) as msg, auth FROM messages WHERE status='0' AND recip='$username' GROUP BY auth");   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $message= " <b><font color=red><p align='center'>You Have " . $row['msg'] . " Unread Messages From ".$row['auth']."</font></b>";
    $link_address = "members2.php?view=".$row['auth'] 

?>
<a href="<?php echo $link_address;?>"> <?php echo $message; ?> </a>
<?php
$query = "UPDATE messages SET status='1' WHERE recip='$username'";
mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

And my update code I want to be this...

```
$query = "UPDATE messages SET status='1' WHERE recip='$username' AND auth='.$row['auth']'";
```

And I want the auth to be the clicked author but `auth='.$row['auth']'` is wrong

Comment: *"And my update code I want to be this...

`UPDATE messages SET status='1' WHERE recip='$username';`"* - Ok, use it. What's the issue with that?

Comment: @Fred-ii- If i add in a query i get an error ... $query = "UPDATE messages SET status='1' WHERE recip='$username'";

Comment: You're going to need to update your question with the actual way you're using it, including any relevant information for it, such as variables and where they're coming from and assigned from.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am not using any form in this code and I think all the necessary information are there :-/

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I updated my code in the question in order to see if you want how i placed my query also these are the errors that i get http://prntscr.com/6pnqxa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74495/discussion-between-niklakis-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Find another way to solve it . 
When I click on the link it goes me to the members2.php?view=userA file so inside this file I just enter this code...

```
$query = "UPDATE messages SET status='1' WHERE recip='$username' AND auth='$view'";
mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
```

And i remove this code ...

```
$query = "UPDATE messages SET status='1' WHERE recip='$username'";
mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
```

From the other file.